# How does Gregorian WEEK_OF_YEAR works

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

Why does `calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` prints 3 instead of 6.

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println("time"+calendar.getTime());
System.out.println("week of year "+calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Output

```
time Tue Feb 09 12:58:02 IST 2021
week of year 3
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

[February 9, 2021 is in week # 6](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021) of the [ISO 8601 week-based year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) of 2021 that runs from Monday January 4, 2021 through Sunday January 2, 2022 (inclusive).

In standard notation, Feb 9, 2021 is the second day Tuesday of the sixth week of the week-based year 2021: 
`2021-W06-2`

## Details

The terrible class `GregorianCalendar` was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

Get current date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

Get the week of a week-based year, using the [definition of ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). In this definition:

- a week runs Monday-Sunday, and
- week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar-year.

As a consequence of that definition, each week-based year has either 52 or
53 whole weeks.

```
int week = today.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

And get the year number of the week-based year for that date. This may differ from the calendar year number in the first and last weeks.

```
int weekYear = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

For example, the ISO 8601 week-based year for 2021 started January 4, 2021. February 9, 2021 is in week # 6.

See [this list of weeks](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021) in ISO 8601 week-based year of 2021.

Comment: Thanks, Basil, I got another doubt, why does it print 7 as the current week is 6

Comment: @saurabhkumar This is week 7, by the definition of ISO 8601. Week # 1 of 2021 started December 28, 2020. There are several definitions of week. You neglected to specify yours.

Comment: calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) this prints 7

Comment: and this  prints 6 -- int week = today.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );

Comment: Which is correct Basil?

Comment: @saurabhkumar My comment was wrong. The ISO 8601 week-based year for 2021 started January 4, 2021. So today Feb 9, 2021 is in week # 6. See this web site for list of weeks: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021

Comment: January 24? you mean 4 right

Comment: @saurabhkumar Yes, correct, now fixed in comment. Thanks! And I added to Answer. I must stop posting before I’ve had my coffee.

Comment: In that case, the year 2020 had 53 weeks, right?

Comment: @saurabhkumar Yes, that same web site shows [53 weeks in ISO 8601 week-based year 2020](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020).

Answer (score 2):

[`calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR) is a constant, you don't use it like that.

You probably meant `calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` (and, today February the 9th it will print 7, not 6, because it's 1-based, not 0-based).

Note that, as the nice answer from Basil Bourque explains, you should use the new DateTime API.

Comment: if it's 1 based then the current week should be 6 right? http://week-number.net/calendar-with-week-numbers-2021.html

Comment: https://www.calendar-365.com/week-number.html

Comment: everywhere it's week 6

Comment: Actually, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) about what counts as first week according to ISO.

Answer (score 2):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

The [answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115789/10819573) nicely explains how to use the Java SE 8 date-time API. If you still want to use the legacy API, you have a couple of options:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Getting current week using SimpleDateFormat
        System.out.println("Current week: " + new SimpleDateFormat("w").format(calendar.getTime()));

        // Getting current week using Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR
        System.out.println("Current week: " + calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Current week: 6
Current week: 6
```

The [ISO 8601 definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) for week 01 is the week with the first `Thursday` of the Gregorian year (i.e. of January) in it. With this definition, week 01 in 2021 starts on 4th January and therefore the current week is the 6th week.

[image]

Comment: In that case, the year 2020 had 53 weeks, right?

Comment: And I have different output than yours Current week: 7
Current week: 7